# How do I select rows where today's date falls in between start and end date inclusive

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 2 columns of data, one startdate and enddate. I want to select rows where entries have start date and/or end date falls on today's date. Refer to diagram below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename
where startdate>=date(now()) and endate<=date(now())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a WHERE clause that will take both columns into account, using an OR condition, so if any of the two are true, the condition validates.

Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE startDate = '2019-01-01' OR endDate = '2019-01-01'
```

Now, if startDate and endDate are just dates, that would work.
But if startDate and endDate are timestamps (full dates plus hours-min-sec..) then it won't be a match.

You'd need to parse the date, like this:

```
WHERE Date_Format(startDate, '%y-%m-%d') = '2019-01-01' 
OR Date_Format(startDate, '%y-%m-%d') = '2019-01-01'
```

Should you want to use the current date instead of a given date:

```
WHERE Date_Format(startDate, '%y-%m-%d') = Date_Format(NOW(), '%y-%m-%d')
OR Date_Format(startDate, '%y-%m-%d') = Date_Format(NOW(), '%y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE startDate = TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN endDate = TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: the answer that you have provided to the question, may be correct, however can you please edit the answer to provider the OP with an explanation as to why you are suggesting to do it this way.